# What does the phrase "I fish hold of it" mean, in the novel "All Quiet on the Western Front"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, literature

I encountered this phrase in the novel *All Quiet on the Western Front*:

> He has buried his face in his hands, his helmet has fallen off I **fish hold** of it and try to put it back on his head.

What does "I fish hold of it" mean here?

Comment: As you must be aware, this book is translated from the German. _Fish hold of_ isn't particularly idiomatic English. Presumably the narrator reaches down to pick up the fallen helmet.

Comment: It looks weird the way you bold it, because they are just two words that happen to be next each other in the sentence.  If you treat them as a unit, that would certainly be weird.  But they are not a unit---it is just a verb, followed by a noun.  I would probably put it something like "after fishing for a hold on it, I put it back on his head", but I don't think inflecting the verb is mandatory, nor the preposition, nor the article.  But with none of those things, it does invite confusion.

Comment: @jjanes I think the preposition *is* mandatory, because "to fish" in this sense is usually considered intransitive, so can't be directly followed by a noun. Your expansion to "fish for a hold" reads a lot more naturally for that reason.

Comment: This is just a bad translation, there are many choices of idiom which match the feel of the German without being weird.  I scoop it up, I scoop hold of it, I reach down for it.

Comment: I hardly ever write this, but we have a site called [english.se] where you can post questions about language found in complex literature.

Comment: It's just an example of a profoundly bad translation, where the translator thought that for some reason he had to "use" the literal words seen in an idiom in the original language. That's all it is.

Comment: As a counterpoint to those saying this is a bad translation, I grew up in central Pennsylvania (lots of German language influence) and this phrase sounds completely natural to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Fish hold of" is unidiomatic as a verb — I can't find another source in Google Books that uses it. It seems like it's some combination of "**fish** for" (NOAD: "search, typically by groping or feeling for something concealed") and "grab **hold of**".

I believe the quote in the question is from Arthur Wesley Wheen's translation. The translation by Brian Murdock uses different words:

> He has pressed his face into his hands. His helmet has rolled off.
> **I reach for it** and try to put it on to his head. He looks up, pushes the helmet away and huddles in under my arm like a child, his head against my chest.

Comment: I am not a fan of Murdock's translation either to be honest, as sounds quite limp.  I would personally go for ''I reach down for it'', ''I scoop it up'' or ''I scoop hold of it'', as this sounds closer to the German without being strange.  In fact, ''I scoop hold of it'' is almost the same except for one word.

Comment: "scoop hold of" definitely doesn't sound idiomatic to me

Comment: @Tom , the thing is, you never, ever, ever, ever translate idioms. Ever. Never, ever, ever. Never! This is the first thing they teach you in Novel Translation School.  :)  There are a zillion self-evident examples of this.  In English we have the tooth fairy, in France they have a little mouse. It's literally "a mistake" by the translator. An editor should have picked it up and fixed it.

Comment: But......you can use an idiom which has a similar ''flavour'' or ''spiciness''?  Obviously I'm not saying it's literally the same, otherwise a reflexive verb would completely change meaning when translated.  This explains why I have started to find a lot of disparities between the ''feel'' of a novel in the original language and the translation.

Answer (score 30):

There is no such expression in English. This is an unusual translation from the original German

> Ich fische ihn heran

I would have translated this as "I fish it up", but the translator went another way. It strikes me as a portmanteau phrase between "fish up" and "grab hold".

Comment: I completely agree, I was just about to post a further comment about it being a portmanteau phrase, but you beat me to it!

Comment: @Andrew https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fishing+up

Comment: Forget fish, go with grab.

Comment: @Andrew It wouldn't have come to my mind, but it fits the pattern of "fish out", "fish for", "fish around", etc, which "fish hold of" certainly doesn't.

Comment: @Esther never heard of it

Comment: AmE speaker here--I didn't even understand it until I saw the answers comparing it to fishing for something.

Comment: I would personally go for ''I scoop it up'' or ''I scoop hold of it'', in fact the latter is the same as the German except for one word.  I'm starting to realise that English translations are often quite bland compared to the way the work was phrased in the original language.

Comment: @Andrew  Data point only. I'm a 71 year old antipodean (NZ). "Fish up" would be a fine enough turn of phrase, need must :-)

Comment: Perfectly explained. The translator was trying to express "a fishing-around-for-it hold".  It's just bad writing.

Comment: [de] native, I'd like to point out that the original sounds odd, too. The entire passage reads like an unedited, Kerouac-y sketch-from-memory narration. In that sense, Wheen's translation may just attempt to conserve this somehow. Even colloquially or in dialect, I wouldn't use *fischen* here because its established meaning in connection with an object (like a ball, for example) is to miss it, not to grab or catch it.

Answer (score 5):

"To fish hold of" something means to pick it up. Often it implies that the object may be in an awkward place so some effort may be needed. It is a BrE colloquial expression.

This passage appears to have been taken from a translation of the original German text by A.W.Wheen. There are many postings of the PDF of this English text on the internet, I found the passage in Chapter 4 page 29 of [this one](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=YXBwcy5kaXN0cmljdDgzMy5vcmd8Y2FyYm9uZWVuZ2xpc2h8Z3g6NzMzYWI5MGM0NDNiNjc0NA). It has been suggested in the comments that the phrase is an error in translation but Wheen was an Australian, a native English speaker. The text was published by Fawcett Crest Books in the USA. As noted in the various comments to answers here, the phrase has other plausible translations.

Comment: Though I've never heard "fish hold" used in the Americas, "fish out" is a common expression there, with similar meaning, i.e., to grab hold of something entangled (as in a net)  and/or out of sight (as a fish below water).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes exactly. In BrE just "to fish" for something has exactly the same meaning (we don't add "out").  Phrases like "Fish in the back of a drawer" imply that there is a lot of stuff in the drawer and you have to rummage through it to find the required object.

Comment: "to fish for something" I know.. I don't know "to fish hold"

Comment: Whose translation? I've never heard "to fish hold of", though "to fish around for" or "to fish (something) out" are common. [UK] NGram's only examples of 'fish hold of' are to do with the fish hold of a fishing vessel: where the fish are held.

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I would say that "fish hold of" is unusual, but OK. "fish for" doesn't necessarily imply success, but "fish old of" can be understood to be short for "fished around for, and got hold of".

Comment: @PeterJennings It's not correct to say that it's a British colloquial expression though, because it simply isn't.  It's something which British people can fairly easily understand as a mangled version of a colloquial expression, most likely as the product of a translator who was not British.

Comment: BrE speaker here, and I would struggle with this sentence, to the point that I would consider it "incorrect". I would expect "fish" to be followed by a preposition ("fish for", "fish in", "fish around"), which is not the case here. The meaning you give seems like a plausible interpretation of the translator's intent, but I'd be interested in any citations you have for similar constructions being used by fluent speakers.

Comment: If you start from the expression "to get/take/catch hold of sth" then you get the above expression by just replacing the verb with "to fish". It might be some stylistic choice by the author/translator (I don't know the original) to indicate that the person is not specifically reaching for the helmet, but rather "fishing" for it, because something else is currently taking his attention.

Comment: I've looked for "fish hold of" in all 17 corpora at ttps://www.english-corpora.org. There are in total two matches. One is this particular text. The other is a different parse (" prior to off loading a full fish hold of Gulf menhaden"). So I would say that, apart from this perverse translation, the phrase does not exist in English.

Comment: @MicSim Certainly, but by what logic can you replace the verb there? What category of verb, or analogous construction, makes that seem like a reasonable thing to do? All the evidence provided so far points to someone taking a German idiom and translated it far too literally.

Comment: Regarding the translator, his name was [Arthur Wheen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Wheen), and he was apparently born and raised in Australia. As with another answer you've misread the name of the publisher as (part of) a person's name.

Comment: ""To fish hold of" something means to pick it up."  That sentence is simply wrong. It's a novel coinage by the writert.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the English editions are using the 1929 translation by [A. W. Wheen](https://archive.org/details/allquietonwester0000eric/page/64/mode/2up?q=%22buried+his+face%22), in which this passage reads:

> He has buried his face in his hands, his helmet has fallen off. I fish hold of it and try to put it back on his head.

Other English translations do exist, however. Here's a [2012 print](https://archive.org/details/allquietonwester0000rema_s0q9/page/58/mode/2up?q=%22His+helmet+has%22) of a 1994 edition whose frontispiece says the translation is (c) Jonathan Cape but whose dust jacket attributes to translation to "Brian Murdoch, Professor of German at Stirling University":

> He has pressed his face into his hands. His helmet has rolled off. I reach for it and try to put it on to his head.

Here is a [1995 translation](https://archive.org/details/allquietonwester00glob/page/30/mode/2up?q=%22has+fallen+off%22) ("abridged and adapted by Earle Rice, Jr.") in simplified English possibly aimed at older children:

> He has covered his face with his hands. His hard hat has fallen off. I grab  hold of it and try to put it back on his head.

If the Wheen translation is not understandable, perhaps one of these other translations might suit your needs.

Comment: "Jonathan Cape" is a publishing company, not a person; they're claiming corporate ownership of the copyright, so there's no contradiction in also crediting a specific individual for creating it.

Answer (score 0):

"I fish hold of it" means "I fish **to catch** hold of it"

---

You can catch a fish, and you can also catch an object.

Catch > to take hold of something, especially something that is moving through the air

From > https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch

Comment: It looks like you're simply adding a word, and then defining that new word. That's not really an answer..